# Is there a way to use CatmullRom interpolation for quaterions?

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I am using the following formula to get the position along a spline in Unity:

```
public Vector3 CatmullRom(float t, Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3 c, Vector3 d)
{
    return (
        (b * 2.0f) +
        (-a + c) * t +
        (a * 2.0f - b * 5.0f + c * 4.0f - d) * t * t +
        (-a + b * 3.0f - c * 3.0f + d) * t * t * t
        ) * 0.5f;
}
```

Given four quaternions, is there a way to find the rotation at each point?